# Netbeans c++ compiler searches for deleted file

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile

I'm working on a Ubuntu 16.04 and Netbeans 8.0.2

I deleted a source file and the corresponding header file, because I had no use for it  anymore.
When I want to compile my code (clean + build), I get the following error:

```
make[2]: *** no rule to make target   source_files/SolveODEwithAST.cpp“, 
benötigt von „build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/source_files/SolveODEwithAST.o“, zu erstellen.  Schluss.
```

-> My makefile is still looking for the deleted file.
I started to search in the makefile for the command to compile this deleted file:

I found the following:
in
Makefile-Release:

```
${OBJECTDIR}/source_files/SolveODEwithAST.o: source_files/SolveODEwithAST.cpp 
${MKDIR} -p ${OBJECTDIR}/source_files
${RM} "$@.d"
$(COMPILE.cc) -O2 -MMD -MP -MF "$@.d" -o ${OBJECTDIR}/source_files/SolveODEwithAST.o source_files/SolveODEwithAST.cpp
```

and it is defined in the OBJECTFILES variable.

I deleted these lines of code, but the lines reappear after building the code.

So how can I change my makefile to make my code work again?

Answer (score 0):

For all files in the projects /nbproject directory I searched for the deleted filenames.

```
$ls
configurations.xml  Makefile-Debug.mk  Makefile-impl.mk  Makefile-Release.mk  Makefile-variables.mk  Package-Debug.bash  Package-Release.bash  private  project.xml
```

It is important to delete the corresponding lines in the .xml files.
When I just delete the corresponding lines in the Makefiles, the lines reappear.